# How can I see a version of a COM DLL registered in Windows

Tags: .net, windows, com

The project I'm working on has a bunch of COM DLLs.

There is an install script that automatically register these DLL for use in other project. Recently there is a bug in the code that cause the program to shutdown inexplicably. Bisect didn't solve the problem (old code that was known to work is now plagued with the same symptom)

I suspect that the uninstall script didn't unregister everything, or something similar problem with the working environment, and I don't have a spare, clean machine to test me theory. Is there any way to see what are the DLL registered within Windows, like their names, version, GUID, etc?

Comment: Do you have access to the script? 
Check script and see what DLLs are registered and from what path (e.g. RegSvr32 ...Name.DLL), before registering it should perform un-register (RegSvr32 -u). 
After check in regedit in path HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\ by DLL Name and see if path was registered properly also there you'll find CLSID and will be able to search whole register by CLSID to see used version, threading model etc...

Comment: I don't have the script (not in readable form anyway) but the regedit trick works. Thanks!

Comment: go in physical location on path indicated in registry - and check version on DLL-file properties. If You have another version and want to use it un-register existent (RegSvr32 -u [DLL Path]), and replace DLL file and re-register it (RegSvr32 [DLL Path])

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a tool called OleView which comes along with windows SDK. E.g. it might be under "Program files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin"

Or, you can simple look for your CLASS GUID in registry under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes.